# Bulk Delete Emails In Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a label where I get my all server alerts, and I did not check counts for a while, now it is over 600,000 and when I am trying to bulk delete it, it gives an error like below.

> Oops, something went wrong
>       Recent changes may not have been saved.

and is there any way to automatically delete emails in any label after 15 days.

I am using G Suite email address.

Answer (score -1):

- type in search: **`label:YOUR_LABEL_UNDER_WHICH_YOU_HAVE_ALL_THOSE_EMAILS`**
- click on the arrow next to the checkbox and select **All**
- click on delete (trash can icon)

[image: 0]

Comment: I am doing it but after sometime it says Oops, something went wrong Recent changes may not have been saved.
At the moment i am deleting in bulk of 10 days and it is deleting fine.
what to do for mails to move to trash after certain time.

Answer (score -1):

1. Select *All* then
2. Click on the link "*Select all elements that match this criteria*"
3. Click the *Delete element*